# Decode a Json string

Tags: php, json

Was wondering how i'd be able to extract the index part of the json in php.
Has been bugging me for ages. Thanks!

```
$ch = curl_init('https://domain.com/blah/blah');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$promo = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$promo = json_decode($promo, true);
```

.

```
{"something":"blahhhh","name":"bob!","id":"7","select":[{"Index":1,"code":"a1","name":"hello","description":"more text"},{"Index":2,"code":"a2","name":"bye","description":"test.."},{"Index":3,"code":"a3","name":"ayeee","description":"Morning!"},{"Index":4,"code":"a4","name":"Cheese!","description":"Yummy!"},{"Index":5,"code":"a5","name":"Water","description":"why is it cloudy? :( "}],"chant":"Free the ducks!","joined":"2015-01-01T16:49:05.000+0000","cool":false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the 2nd parameter of json_decode is set to true the function return an associative array who's really close to the structure of the JSON.

From there all what you got to do is put back the JSON path into an associative php array to access the wanted value !

```
foreach($promo['select'] as $select){
    echo $select['Index'].' ';
}
```

example : http://codepad.org/OMg7WTr0

If you're looking to extract other value and you don't figure out the path just do `var_dump($promo);` it will give you a clear view of the array path to use

Comment: Thanks! How would i individually get them, instead of together?